# Events for telerik hierarchical subgrid

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgridview, hierarchical

Telerik grid has several events like `UserAddedRow` and `RowsChanged` which are fired when I add/edit row on master grid.

I can't find equivalent events for a hierarchical subgrid.

Can somebody give me some direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Same event will be fired for the child templates as well, so you do not need to look for equivalents.

Comment: For edit it is also Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView.RowsChanged, like for main grid. This is true. But for added row, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView.UserAddedRow is not fired for subgrid...

Comment: I have tested the events prior posting and both are fired for child templates as well. Now I double checked to make sure, and the UserAddedRow fires just fine.